# What is wrong/what did I do wrong on boot? Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: networking, pi-4, boot, boot-issues, headless

I just got my Pi on Christmas and I mostly use it for Discord bot hosting and now I am interested into turning it into a NAS.

I followed [Network Chucks video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyMpI8csWis&ab_channel=NetworkChuck) after I installed the Open Media Vault my Pi rebooted and after that it wouldn't connect to my network I check all other connected devices and it's not there. The red LED light is on and stable the green ACT light is fine once powered on then after a bit it just stops sometimes I see a blink only a single one. I had modified my `/etc/fstab` file to auto mount three `ext4` thumb drives. Two of them are 64 GB and the other is 32 GB. After I modified the `/etc/fstab`, I did a reboot to test if I bricked my Pi but no, it worked fine. I have also had this problem when trying to start a raid with those same three thumb drives. I don't know if it's not booting or if my Pi is just not connecting to the Wi-Fi.

- Using a Raspberry Pi 4 model B+ 2 GB
- I am running the Pi headless.
- SD card is a [SanDisk ultra 64 GB](https://a.co/d/9t6nQHX)
- Heatsinks are on on and I feel the heatsinks warm.

The only things connected to my Pi is the power to the Pi and my USB hub that has three thumb drives connected. I have booted/rebooted with all the thumb drives connected and no errors.

There is not much on the Pi, it's just my Discord bot that I can easily recover by tossing my SD card into my PC and getting the file.

As of right now I am doing testing wirelessly once everything works and I get it all setup I do plan to have it wired to the router.

I made a new clean install on a secondary 9 GB SD card. I only installed OMV with no other connections to the thumb drives that I used. It booted up its connected to the Wi-Fi but I can't SSH into it. The reason is:

```
ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.147 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Before, with the other 64 GB SD card, it wouldn't boot or connect to the Wi-Fi. It just removed from the Wi-Fi. It connected then it disconnected and now it's in repeat. I think OMV is doing something to my Pi that causes it to brick or I am just dumb and blind.

Comment: you didn't mention if you connect the pi wirelessly or ethernet

Comment: I updated the post. I have been using wireless @JaromandaX

Comment: Even Chuck warned that wifi is not a good idea for this, I think that was just around the 4th coffee break :p

Comment: Yea but thats for the actual stuff. I do plan on putting it on ethernet as soon as it can boot up and connect :(

Comment: If you cannot connect it to a screen and keyboard you are probably wasting your time trying to get this working blind.

Comment: So in other words I am F'ed? @goldilocks

Comment: I wouldn't say that.  I'd say it's all about how much you consider your time to be worth.  You can diddle around applying random suggestions from the internet until you get lucky (and hope that you are not just digging a deeper hole) for as long as you like, or you can try and scrounge up an HDMI screen to use for a few hours, and buy a USB keyboard for ~$10.  Obviously that in itself is not a solution, but I think it will put you on a much better path to finding one -- plus this is almost certainly only the *first* such problem you'll hit that warrants that kind of attention.

Comment: Ok got it. I can look around to see if I have them if not then I will try to buy them. Thank you.

Comment: @goldilocks I looked and it shows this message on repeat https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/904600965775253564/1064055259640647680/20230114_213422.jpg

Comment: I have now fixed it. Thank you my sweet sweet supposed human @goldilocks

Comment: Glad to hear it!